# H3 is taking more space than enclosing div

Tags: html, css

I have a web page like this.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div style="background:blue">
        <h3 style="background:green">Hello world.</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I analyze the output in chrome, it seems that the h3 tag is taking more space than the div tag. I want the div tag to completely include the h3 tag, and the background color of div to be shown in the entire area. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: `div { display: inline-block; }` `h3 { line-height: 0; }`

Comment: What you're seeing is called *margin collapse*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that some elements have browser styling by default, that is why you should always use a [css reset](http://www.cssreset.com/):

if you float the div it will wrap around the element, and set the margin of the h3 to 0.

```
<div style="background:blue;float:left;">
   <h3 style="background:green;margin:0;">Hello world.</h3>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZWde/)

For the div to take the entire screen's size remove the float.

```
<div style="background:blue;">
 <h3 style="background:green;margin:0;">Hello world.</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Floating is not needed at all; setting the margin to 0 is enough.

Comment: @LeBen i spaced out on the take the entire screen requirement :D edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I guess we too are friends now.

Comment: @Thomas Why change the accepted answer to a lower quality one 2 weeks after it solved your problem ?

Comment: I changed it back, Happy now?

Answer (score 3):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RhQA3/)**

**CSS**

```
.div1{
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}
h3{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:green;
```

}

**[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/RhQA3/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Set a `font-size` and `line-height` on the `h3` like so:

```
h3 { 
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1em; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Taken a css reset? This set all to default values.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 2):

Most simple solution I see, add `overflow: hidden;` to the enclosing div.

Answer (score 2):

```
<h3 style="background:green;margin:0;">Hello world.</h3>
```

By default h3 has a margin associated with it. So you have to add a margin:0 to the h3 tag.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pPA6N/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

set margin of h3 to 0.This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by increasing the line height of h3.